# Why is UTF-8 encoding working in simple Java project but not in Android?

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8

I've trouble with the UTF-8 character encoding. My android application which is loading content through a server from a mysql database isn't showing special characters like (é, í, ü, ö, ä etc) correctly.

I have tried the following:

1. I took a look into my database, all looks good.  (utf8_unicode_ci)
2. I have created a simple Java Project, working directly on my database by using my own database framework. All looks good!
3. I have created a simple Java Project, using the same code (except the AsyncTask) to request data from the database through my server. All looks good!
4. I took a look into the server log files, the response which was send
   back to the client looks good!
5. I took a look at the incoming data, the string looks broken!!! To convert it afterwards e.g. via `new String(line.getBytes(), "utf-8")´ isn't working.

Number 5 Looks good for a normal java project but my Android app is getting in trouble. 
For that, I use the following code:

```
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object> {

    private static final String LOG_CLASS = Sender.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String host = "xxx";
    private static final String port = "8080";
    private static final String serverUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/WebService/HomeServlet";


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object ... request) {

        final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);

        final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SOAP", WsUtils.parseObjectToSoap(request[0])));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    Log.i(LOG_CLASS, "Calling Server: " + serverUrl);

                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    final StringBuilder soapMessage = new StringBuilder();

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.i(LOG_CLASS, "xxxxxxxx: " + new String(line.getBytes(), "utf-8"));
                        soapMessage.append(line);
                    }

                    final String fullQualifiedClassName = WsUtils.identifySoapMessage(soapMessage.toString());
                    final Object parsedSoapCall = WsUtils.parseSoapToObject(fullQualifiedClassName, soapMessage.toString());

                    return parsedSoapCall;

                } finally {
                    instream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_CLASS, "Encoding is not supported: " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_CLASS, "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_CLASS, "IOException: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }


        Log.e(LOG_CLASS, "Error while loading data from Server");
        return null;
    }

}
```

This part of the Server is sending the response. The log message shows no encoding issues.

```
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7376640150158278177L;

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HomeServlet.class);
    private Processing processing = new Processing();

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

            final String soapMessage = req.getParameter("SOAP");

            /* do some work */

            /* Process request (Database processing etc.) */
            final String response = processing.process(parsedSoapCall);
            LOG.info("Incoming request processed, back to client: " + response);

            /* Sending response back to client */
            if (null != response) {
                final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
                writer.println(response);
            }

        }

    }
```

Connection String from DataBase class:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + dbUserName + "&password=" + dbPassword + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true");
```

Issue solved: 
The issue was caused by a missing encoding in the header of the Webserver.
I've added the encoding to the header, now it's working fine. HttpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html"); 
HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Thanks, guys.

Comment: It isn't showing it correctly **in what**? The output device / output method is missing. PS I would strongly recommend replacing the log statements with a specific exception and not perform error handling through `return null`.

Comment: In my LogCat, e.g. where i've added the xxxxxxxx log.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1590

Comment: `line.getBytes()` you don't specify which encoding you want here.

Comment: It is not only in the LogCat, it's everywhere. In my controls (TextView, ListView, Buttons etc). Don't think it is a LogCat issue

Comment: @njzk2 Just as with the answer of Louis, as UTF-8 is the default char set, it should not matter (although it would certainly improve the code).

Comment: You could check if the server is sending you the correct character set by using e.g. Wireshark or a proxy. I doubt that it is somewhere in this code as UTF-8 is already the default... As Java has a different character set (Windows-1252) it could well be that the characters were changed from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 before.

Comment: in the database connection in the server, are you specifying to receive UTF-8?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead: my point exactly. If the behavior is different from the Java app, it probably is related to the Java app not using UTF-8 as a default encoding, and probably the server not sending utf-8 data.

Comment: I have added the necessary code from the server.

Comment: OK, so that rules out the DB connection. Leaving the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `InputStream` and an `InputStreamReader` to get a `String` out of the entity line-by-line, try using:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

It will correctly autodetect the encoding used in the HTTP response and specified in the headers.

Comment: My String is a formatted xml String, it consist of many lines. I need it line by line.

Comment: Don't worry, EntityUtils.toString() will convert the entire HTTP response body to a string, so you will obtain all lines and newlines without doing it manually.

Comment: Use the `InputStreamReader` with the result of [`getContentEncoding()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentEncoding())?

Comment: Ah, entity.getContentEncoding() returns null. HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); Log.i(LOG_CLASS, "xxxxxxxx: " + entity.getContentEncoding()); - but why?

Comment: I've added the encoding to the header. Now it's working fine. response.setContentType("text/html"); response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") - Thanks, guys.

Comment: You're welcome, glad we got you thinking in the right direction. If it is XML then `text/xml` should work too.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to change

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(instream);
```

to

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8");
```

although UTF-8 is already the default character set for Android.

Comment: Just wanted to post the same, but isn't UTF-8 already the platform default charset for Android?

Comment: I've replaced this code section, doesn't help. I think i've tried about 5 others ways for UTF-8 converting ... :/

Comment: Downvoted because the default character set of Android is [UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4564732/589259)